# Exclude latest post from category X but display the rest?

Tags: wordpress, posts

I would like to show all posts but only exclude the NEWEST post from the 'Featured' category, other posts from this cat should display. Any idea what I should add to the loop to achieve this? I don't understand it!

Comment: You can edit your own question. Don't add answers that aren't answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
query_posts(array('paged' => $paged, 'category_name' => 'featured', 'offset' => '1'));
if(have_posts() : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
// blah blah layout here
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query;
```

Comment: How can I use this to show all other posts from other cats aswell?

Comment: That's a bit more tricky. Perhaps it would be better to know *why* you want to do that.  Are you trying to skip the first post in the "Featured" category because you're already displaying it somewhere else in the page?  If that's the case, how are you doing that? Is it via a separate query? If it's not the case, why do you want to skip it? If you just don't want it to show, then set it as a draft. Then it won't show.  But it would help to know *why* you want to do this - then a proper solution can be given.